# React Native Google Places API restriction issue

Tags: react-native, google-places-api, android-restrictions

I get the following error while using `React Native Google Places autocomplete`.

> This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API
>   key...

I'm using a `Google Places API` Web Service key, which restrictions on Android-App.
This one is restricted with the package name `com.xxx.xxx.debug` and `com.xxx.xxx.test`. Another API key is restricted to `com.xxx.xxx`.
I've added the proper `SHA-1` key.

Anyone has a clue what I'am doing wrong or why it doesn't work?
I've checked the docs of Google and tried out many different things, still I cannot get it to work with a restriction.

Comment: Same issue here, was there any solution for this? - I have actually the same behaviour on both ios and android... I checked bundle ids and package names and sha-1. I think all is in place.

Answer (score 0):

Add your `React-Native` android package id to the key you are using for `Google Places API`. You can find it in **Project(Root Folder)** => **android** => **app** => **build.gradle** => **application id**

Comment: In the Google Console or the actual key in react native?
Adding appId to key results in Key not valid error.

Comment: in your `Google Console` you have to add the package name and your `SHA-1` key

Comment: I did that. The appId is com.xxx.xxx and we use a suffix for debug and test enviroments. So added 2 restrictions. com.xxx.xxx.debug and com.xxx.xxx.test with the right SHA-1 keys

Comment: Can you remove the restriction for the key and try once? and make sure you have enabled google place api

Comment: But I need to put on restrictions, since otherwise the key can be abused.